# How can I overwrite setInterval with a mock for a test in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Background: I'm trying to convert a mocha test suite from JavaScript to TypeScript. One issue that happened with the library in the past was that it would Error in Electron because it expected `setInterval` to return an object with an `unref()` method, which is the case in Node.js, but not in Electron. The issue was fixed, and a test was written.

[The test](https://github.com/nfriedly/express-rate-limit/blob/cdb6db46a7c5620bd449abe1537aa04fee7cc879/test/memory-store-test.js#L135-L164) temporarily replaces the global `setInterval()` method with a mocked one that only returns numbers, and validates that the library behaves properly:

```
  describe("timeout", function() {
    const originalSetInterval = setInterval;
    let timeoutId = 1;
    let realTimeoutId: Timeout;

    beforeEach(function() {
      timeoutId = 1;
      // eslint-disable-next-line  no-global-assign
      setInterval = function(callback: () => any, timeout: number) {
        realTimeoutId = originalSetInterval(callback, timeout);
        return timeoutId++;
      };
    });

    it("can run in electron where setInterval does not return a Timeout object with an unset function", function(done) {
      const store = new MemoryStore(-1);
      const key = "test-store";

      store.incr(key, function(err, value) {
        if (err) {
          done(err);
        } else {
          if (value === 1) {
            done();
          } else {
            done(new Error("incr did not set the key on the store to 1"));
          }
        }
      });
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      // eslint-disable-next-line  no-global-assign
      setInterval = originalSetInterval;
      clearTimeout(realTimeoutId);
    });
  });
```

TypeScript throws the error `TS2539: Cannot assign to 'setInterval' because it is not a variable.` where setInterval is overwritten and again where it's restored.

Is there a way to disable that error for this test and let `setInterval` be writeable?